# Transfer images to server using PHP

Tags: php, upload, image

I have some pictures that are online, the images are simple http://domain.com/pic.jpg for example; there's an upload feature but that's for user upload
the user won't upload, it's an auto upload.
This mean I have the Urls on an array and I want that php auto upload those Urls photo into the server
Any help!! Thanks

Comment: None of that made very much sense to me.

Comment: this don't need to i think it's simple an cler and jesper just answered it :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
define('IMAGE_PATH', '/path/to/images');

foreach ($urlArray as $url) {
    file_put_contents(IMAGE_PATH . "/" . basename($url), file_get_contents($url));
}
```

This would require that the user Apache is running under has write access to the IMAGE_PATH. Also, this might not be the exact solution in your case. You seem to be in need of a database to store these filenames, which then probably should be wearing ids instead of their original filenames.

Comment: You should change the filename before storing or block script execution under IMAGE_PATH using .htaccess. Suppose someone will pass mydomain.com/my_evil_script.php as image URL.